# Get messages from Telegram channel that I'm not admin

Tags: php, telegram

How can I get messages from Telegram channel if I'm not admin there?
I just watched out official documentation and didn't find any method that can help me. Can I do it somehow?

Looking for PHP solution (desirable).

Comment: You need to build (or download) a php telegram bot with the help of the API : https://core.telegram.org/bots

Comment: @Calimero, but I didn't find any method to get **channel updates** if I'm not admin there.

Answer (score 2):

The official way is to create a telegram bot and interact in php through the bot API.

In the case you want to listen to channel updates without being administrator (which is not officially supported by telegram at the moment), an alternative is to use unofficial libraries such as https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto

Comment: Should I use **get_dialogs** method for this? Or another one?

Comment: read the (long) page, the answer is in it. `$updates = $MadelineProto->API->get_updates(['offset' => $offset, 'limit' => 50, 'timeout' => 1]);`